# What is a Trump Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word (or phrase) conforms to a special rule (and it's a fantastic rule, believe me!) I call it a Trump Word™.  Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Trump Words™ | Not Trump Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ALTERNATIVE | MAINSTREAM |
| BELIEVE ME | SKEPTICAL |
| CHRISTIANITY | ISLAM |
| CONSERVATIVE | LIBERAL |
| ECONOMY | SOCIALISM |
| FOSSIL FUEL | CLIMATE CHANGE |
| FOX NEWS | MSNBC |
| GORSUCH | GARLAND |
| HUGE | BIG |
| IVANKA | CHELSEA |
| LAW AND ORDER | PROTESTS |
| MANUFACTURING | CHINA |
| MILITARY | PACIFISM |
| REPUBLICAN | DEMOCRAT |
| RUSSIAN | ARAB |
| TEXAS | CALIFORNIA |
| TRUMP | CLINTON |
| TWITTER | FACEBOOK |
| TWO | SECOND |
| USA | GLOBAL |
| WALL | OPEN BORDER |
| WEALTHY | POOR |
| WINNER | LOSER |
| WISCONSIN | MINNESOTA |
| XENOPHOBIA | IMMIGRATION |
| ZIONISM | PALESTINE |

CSV version:

```
Trump Words™,Not Trump Words™
ALTERNATIVE,MAINSTREAM
BELIEVE ME,SKEPTICAL
CHRISTIANITY,ISLAM
CONSERVATIVE,LIBERAL
ECONOMY,SOCIALISM
FOSSIL FUEL,CLIMATE CHANGE
FOX NEWS,MSNBC
GORSUCH,GARLAND
HUGE,BIG
IVANKA,CHELSEA
LAW AND ORDER,PROTESTS
MANUFACTURING,CHINA
MILITARY,PACIFISM
REPUBLICAN,DEMOCRAT
RUSSIAN,ARAB
TEXAS,CALIFORNIA
TRUMP,CLINTON
TWITTER,FACEBOOK
TWO,SECOND
USA,GLOBAL
WALL,OPEN BORDER
WEALTHY,POOR
WINNER,LOSER
WISCONSIN,MINNESOTA
XENOPHOBIA,IMMIGRATION
ZIONISM,PALESTINE
```

As usual, the rule has nothing to do with the meaning of the words, only their orthography.

Comment: I bet it's something to do with a wall :P

Comment: @dan04 NSA is now probably snooping your account :)

Comment: Trump words are the best. They are fantastic words, just the best. It's true.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Trump Word™ ...

> ... has at least one of the letters U, V, W, X, Y or Z in it. None of the Not Trump Words™ have any of these letters in them.

They are called Trump Words™, ...

> ... because the included letters are the "high" letters at the end of the alphabet that trump the lower letters? Or maybe the highest-scoring letter where the score is the position of the letter in the alphabet scores more than 20 and hence is a trump? Not sure.
>
>  (I tried to find a card game where trumps score more than 20 points, because U is the 21st letter in the alphabet, but I couldn't find anything useful.)

Comment: Notice all the T's are a bit wonky in the table. I think the letters after T are perhaps the T-rump of the alphabet.

Comment: The wonky Ts are a perennial feature, nothing specific to this puzzle.

Comment: (But I like the T-rump idea, regardless.)